# How do I handle such list inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I take such an input from the user-

[image]

Then i try to split it using comma and append it into a list as numbers.

But whenever I do so , it gives out an error and the only stores "20,340,2".

Notice how the last number for the first line is 223, however, my list only stores 2 and ignores the 23 at the end, even though i've used comma to separate the elements. Same for 789 as well (next line). It stops at 78 and ignores the 9 below, although it is the same number
Can somebody please help me take a such inputs and separates each element properly using commas and stores it in a list as numbers?
Thank you.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using as well. You have a space between 2 and 23. Which is most likely why you are getting an error when splitting the list.

Comment: problem is that there are spaces between numbers. You would have to split by comma and by space to get it.

Comment: If the number is supposed to be 223 rather than two separate numbers 2 and 23, you need to remove spaces, not split on them.

Comment: Sorry, ive attached an image of the kind of input i want. It gives out an error right after encounters the next line after 2.

Comment: Well that's a syntax error, because you can't write a single-quoted string literal across multiple lines like that. If your code is actually getting past that and storing anything in a list then there is something you're not showing us, because this program should fail before there is any opportunity to split on commas.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to allow numbers with spaces in them, you could start by just removing all spaces from the string:

```py
>>> s = '120,340,2 23,456,678,78 9,456'
>>> s.replace(' ', '')
'120,340,223,456,678,789,456'
```

From there, you can split on commas and parse the parts as numbers.

Comment: Added an image of the kind of input i want.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
input='120,340,200,240,21,2,9,5,300'
input.replace(" ","") #removes spaces

input_array=input.split(",") #creates array, although they are still strings

for i in range(len(input_array)): #for every number in the list, replace the string with the number.
    input_array[i]=int(input_array[i])

print(input_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

If in fact this is coming from an input file that you read it would look like:

```
  input = '120,340,2\n        23,456,678,78\n       9,456'
```

when read.

This results in a number of different problems. One of which is that you have read until the second delimiting single quote to make it work.

Then you get something like:

```
input = '120,340,2\n        23,456,678,78\n       9,456'
input = input.replace(" ","")
input = input.replace("\n","")
```